# cURL does not work but same site works with browser

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

what are the reasons for when using cURL form linux server to access the site  return an error. but opening this site in chrome succeeds.

Comment: There are a few reasons, but off the top of my head, I'd suggest that it may be because your cURL call doesn't include headers (or cookies) that the page is expecting to have in the request. If you open the url in a new private window in your browser, what happens?

Comment: Had same problem. That was because of user agent and compression gzip are not in headers.

Comment: can you provide `curl request` you made with error produced by it.

Comment: I think the problem is with SSL error. Can anyone tell me how to fix it on client side and also server side

Comment: @daf works with private window in the browser

Answer (score 12):

Look browsers headers while sending your request, and add same headers to cURL request. Some servers needs some headers that browsers sends default but not cURL.

Comment: this solved my issue. server wanted a user-agent header.

Comment: Good advice. In my case it was missing `--digest` and `-c cookies.txt`

Comment: I had to include user-agent and accept. This actually fixed an issue I had with Apache HttpClient. The exceptions weren't particularly useful, so I was scratching my head over this for days. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**I had `301 Moved Permanently` error on curl but was working on browser.**

But when I looked deeper there's `Location` to moved to location, which would be working. This coulde be when the server is using TLS.

```
$ curl -v http://www.shaharma.com/location/v1/US/zipcode/98104
*   Trying 172.111.99.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.shaharma.com (172.111.99.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /location/v1/US/zipcode/98104 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.shaharma.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://www.shaharma.com/location/v1/US/zipcode/98104
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Expires: Fri, 01 Dec 2017 19:40:14 GMT
< Date: Fri, 01 Dec 2017 19:40:14 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Set-Cookie: UID=52679eee-c06c-49fc-893a-69fd7e46bad0; expires=Fri, 25-Feb-2028 19:40:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.shaharma.com
< Set-Cookie: SID=1ada5fa9-0ace-4f4e-b75b-7a756b8da934; path=/; domain=.shaharma.com
< Set-Cookie: shaharma_loc_lb=p-loc-w; expires=Fri, 01-Dec-2017 19:50:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.shaharma.com
< Set-Cookie: bby_rdp=l; expires=Sat, 02-Dec-2017 19:40:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.shaharma.com
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.shaharma.com left intact
```

**Also, you can goto brower and see the network which will have headers information.**

[image: headers]

Answer (score 1):

To avoid/suppress SSL error, use `-k` flag, ie

```
curl -k ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I configured the certificate generated with [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) in nginx like this:

```
ssl_certificate /root/.acme.sh/my.domain.com_ecc/my.domain.com.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /root/.acme.sh/my.domain.com_ecc/my.domain.com.key;
```

But I needed to configure it using the fullchain certificate:

```
ssl_certificate /root/.acme.sh/my.domain.com_ecc/fullchain.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /root/.acme.sh/my.domain.com_ecc/my.domain.com.key;
```